# Word for dry, stinging/burning eyes?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for more words that might describe dry, stinging, burning, or an almost cracking feeling of the eyes.

I wanted to use "cracked eyes", but I'm already using the phrase "cracked lips". I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who is dehydrated and lost in the woods--specifically an adjective related to very dry, irritated eyes.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you want to use it?  Are you looking for a noun or adjective or..?

Comment: If it fits your purpose, I recommend using figurative language, but we'd need an example sentence. Otherwise **bloodshot** comes to mind.

Comment: I wanted to use cracked eyes, but I'm already using the phrase cracked lips. I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who is dehydrated and lost in the woods--specifically an adjective related to very dry, irritated eyes.

Answer (score 2):

As someone who has suffered from very dry eyes in real life, I would suggest "sandy" or "gritty".  That's exactly what it feels like.

Answer (score 0):

**Dry eyes** is the medical term used to describe this condition [1](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/dry-eyes/basics/definition/con-20024129).

Answer (score 0):

**[desiccated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/desiccate)** is a good word for something being harshly dry, but it is not specific to eyes, so you would still have to write "desiccated eyes."

**[Bleary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleary)** is a word specific to eyes that are unfocused, possibly by fatigue, but not necessarily by being dry.

> of the eyes or vision :  dull or dimmed especially from fatigue or sleep

The word **[blear](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20bleary&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS734US735&oq=define%20blear&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i57j69i60j0l2.1384j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20blear)** can be a noun, but it likewise doesn't imply dryness.

> a film over the eyes; a blur.

You could combine the words if you want to emphasize the condition with colorful language:

> His vision was obscured by a **dessicated blear**.

If you're going to take this approach to describing the person's state, you have a lot of options.  A thesaurus would give plenty of variations.